# How to pass an array of structures in a function?

Tags: c, struct, expression

### About to ready to give up on this

Been having an issue with my code for hours, has been telling me I have an error about the error: expected expression before 'Robot_t' and cannot find a solution, if anyone has a working solution you will save me
This is the error message provided

```
Arrayintofn.c: In function 'main':
Arrayintofn.c:23:23: error: expected expression before 'Robot_t'
     loading_Profiles (Robot_t RobotInfo[]);
```

No matter what I do or who I consult there is no solution

Here is the code as well

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
  {
    int Robot_Number;
    char Robot_Name[30];
    int Year_Manufacturer;
    float Top_Speed;
    float Mass;
    float Best_Score;
} Robot_t;

void loading_Profiles();

int main()
{
    Robot_t RobotInfo[5];

    loading_Profiles (Robot_t RobotInfo[]);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
 
        printf("%d\t\t%s\t\t%d\t\t\t%.2f\t\t%.2f\t\t%.2f\n",
                RobotInfo[i].Robot_Number, RobotInfo[i].Robot_Name,
               RobotInfo[i].Year_Manufacturer, RobotInfo[i].Top_Speed, 
               RobotInfo[i].Mass, RobotInfo[i].Best_Score);
 
    }
 
    return 0;
}

void loading_Profiles()
{
    int Counter = 0;
    int i;

    Robot_t RobotInfo[5];

    FILE *ROBOTtxt = fopen("Robot.txt", "r");

    if (ROBOTtxt == NULL) {
        perror("an error occured during the loading of the file\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        char LineNumber[100] = "";
        fgets(LineNumber, 100, ROBOTtxt);
        sscanf(LineNumber, "%d %s %d %f %f %f",
                &RobotInfo[i].Robot_Number,
                RobotInfo[i].Robot_Name,
                &RobotInfo[i].Year_Manufacturer,
                &RobotInfo[i].Top_Speed,
                &RobotInfo[i].Mass,
                &RobotInfo[i].Best_Score);

        Counter++;

        if (feof(ROBOTtxt)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (ferror(ROBOTtxt)) {
        perror("an error has occured");
        exit(-1);
    }

    fclose(ROBOTtxt);
}
```

Comment: No sorry, that was me and my friends hours ago still with no solution

Comment: I think you are confusing a function declaration with a function call. `Robot_t RobotInfo[]` should appear inside the parenthesis in the declaration. It should not appear in the body of the function. In the call you need just `RobotInfo`. I recommend re-reading the chapter on functions in your C book.

Comment: @Zac Nicholson - The comment to the other question solves exactly the problem you present; still you didn't incorporate the solution into your code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your function loading_Profiles() written like this doesnt accept any parameters but you pass an array in the main function. You should rewrite the declaration as
   "void loading_Profiles(Robot_t arr_name[])"
2. In the main function you should pass an argument only by its name. So instead of this:
   "loading_Profiles(Robot_t RobotInfo[]);"
   just pass:
   "loading_Profiles(RobotInfo);"

Comment: Note that  `void loading_Profiles();` at the top of the program is a **declaration** meaning the function accepts an *unspecified* number of arguments of an unspecified type.  It is obsolete and **not** a prototype saying the function takes no parameters.  That would be `void loading_Profiles(void);`  They are not the same.

Comment: Yes, i apologize.

Answer (score 0):

There were a number of errors in your code, I'll paste my commented solution below, but for reference:

- in the `loading_Profiles` prototype you weren't specifying a parameter
- in the `main`, you were calling the function uncorrectly
- inside the `loading_Profiles` implementation, you were trying to work on a local array, and not the one passed as an argument.

Also, sometimes you were using 50, sometimes 5? Which is it?

Here's the code, tested using a file generated on Mockaroo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
  {
    int Robot_Number;
    char Robot_Name[30];
    int Year_Manufacturer;
    float Top_Speed;
    float Mass;
    float Best_Score;
} Robot_t;

void loading_Profiles(Robot_t RobotInfo[]);  // added parameter to prototype

int main()
{
    Robot_t RobotInfo[50]; // 50 instead of 5

    loading_Profiles(RobotInfo); // simply pass your variable

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
 
        printf("%d\t\t%s\t\t%d\t\t\t%.2f\t\t%.2f\t\t%.2f\n",
                RobotInfo[i].Robot_Number, RobotInfo[i].Robot_Name,
               RobotInfo[i].Year_Manufacturer, RobotInfo[i].Top_Speed, 
               RobotInfo[i].Mass, RobotInfo[i].Best_Score);
 
    }
 
    return 0;
}

void loading_Profiles(Robot_t RobotInfo[]) // added parameter
{
    int Counter = 0;
    int i;

    FILE *ROBOTtxt = fopen("Robot.txt", "r");
    
    //Robot_t RobotInfo[5]; // removed, work on the array passed as argument, not a local one
    
    if (ROBOTtxt == NULL) {
        perror("an error occured during the loading of the file\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        char LineNumber[100] = "";
        fgets(LineNumber, 100, ROBOTtxt);
        sscanf(LineNumber, "%d %s %d %f %f %f",
                &RobotInfo[i].Robot_Number,
                RobotInfo[i].Robot_Name,
                &RobotInfo[i].Year_Manufacturer,
                &RobotInfo[i].Top_Speed,
                &RobotInfo[i].Mass,
                &RobotInfo[i].Best_Score);

        Counter++;

        if (feof(ROBOTtxt)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (ferror(ROBOTtxt)) {
        perror("an error has occured");
        exit(-1);
    }

    fclose(ROBOTtxt);
}
```

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

While declaring parameter for the function you need to specify variable type as structure and create an array of structure type.

```
void loading_Profiles(Robot_t RobotInfo[]) // added parameter
```